# Movie/Animation having an immortal man trying to revive his brother after 3000 years

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to recall the title of an animated movie I watched as a kid long ago. I'm not even sure it was a movie (though if it was it's probably an animated one), but I remember I watched it on TV. The plot is sort of as below, where (xyz?) denotes parts that I'm not sure and could be something similar.

There was a legend of two close brothers in ancient times, (who were strong warriors?). Something happened and one of them (died?), then no one heard of the other. It was believed that (either the two were immortal, or the surviving one turned immortal in that event?).

Some 3000 years later, a group including the protagonist is trying to solve some (mystery?). Investigation relates it to the two brothers' legend, then one in the group figures the survived brother should still be alive and probably has accumulated a lot of wealth. It turns out that brother did become very rich and currently the owner of a huge/very powerful corporation.

He has been preparing for an upcoming significant event, which hasn't happened for at least 3000 years (and also is the chance to revive his brother?). The group (tries to stop him?) for some reason.

Comment: http://www.veryabc.cn/movie/uploads/script/tmnt.txt might help kinda has description of what you are talking about

Comment: The script did point me to the correct movie. Perhaps I was mixing it up with other stories about the two brothers part.

Comment: What was the movies name

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/movie-animation-having-an-immortal-man-trying-to-revive-his-brother-after-3000-y#comment389044_145716), it seems that this is a partial recollection (along with other stories, especially for the "brother" part) of the 2007 [*Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453556) movie. It was CGI, which would fit the "animation" OP was remembering.

**It was believed that (either the two were immortal, or the surviving one turned immortal in that event.**

From the intro:

> An evil born 3000 years ago. It was in that time that a warrior king named Yoatl led a brotherhood that fought side by side with one purpose: to conquer all the kingdoms of the world. Nothing could stand in their way as they left a trail of destruction behind them.  In his quest, the warrior learned of a constellation known as the Stars of Kikan. **Every 3000 years, the stars would align, opening a portal to a world of unknown power. He became immortal, but at a price**.

The guy doesn't have a brother *per se* (at least not that we know of), but his companions are referred to as his "brotherhood", who were turned to stone.

**Some 3000 years later, a group including the protagonist is trying to solve some (mystery?). Investigation relates it to the two brothers' legend, then one in the group figures the survived brother should still be alive and probably has accumulated a lot of wealth.**

The events take place 3000 years after the intro. The turtles have split up, but are later bourght back together and investigate April's boss, a rich guy named Max Winters. Winter turns out to be Yoatl.

**It turns out that brother did become very rich and currently the owner of a huge/very powerful corporation.**

Winters is the boss, and presumed founder, of Winterscorp:

> "You've never heard of Winterscorp?"
>
> "That's what I'm telling you."
>
> "They're into everything: Real estate, technology, pharmaceuticals, hair gel."

**He has been preparing for an upcoming significant event, which hasn't happened for at least 3000 years (and also is the chance to revive his brother?).**

Winters/Yaotl replicates the event from 3000 years ago. Upon this, his generals are indeed "revived" of sorts.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would remember the immortal villain thing, but no four human-sized turtles and a rat doing ninja stuff but you know... Just in case :)